# Before_save methods are not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

My model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save [:method1!, :method2!]
  #..........

  private

  def method1!
    puts 'method1'
  end

  def method2!
    puts 'method2'
  end
end
```

The methods `method1` and `method2` aren't not called for some reason when I save a model. Is there any error in my code?

Comment: Do the methods work when called individually (ie `before_save :method1!` not using an array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify the model

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :method1!, :method2!
  #..........

  private

  def method1!
    puts 'method1'
  end

  def method2!
    puts 'method2'
  end
end
```

I think it will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
  before_save do
    method1!
  end

private
  def method1!
    puts "method1!"
  end